# Is there a difference in byte data type for OSX and Windows

Tags: java, arrays

I am using a data type of byte array declared as:

```
byte[] sendbuf= new byte[64];
```

Later, I call:

```
dev.write(sendbuf);  // see class code below for this
```

Can anyone tell me why under OSX 10.7.5 all works fine but under Windows XP I get an exception  "The parameter is incorrect"?  Is there a difference in data types between the two operating systems?

The HIDDevice.class is:

```
public native int write(byte[] data) throws IOException;

/**
 * Read an Input Report to a HID device.
 *
 * @param buf a buffer to put the read data into
 * @return the actual number of bytes read 
 * @throws IOException if read error occured
 */
```

Here is the error:

```
java.io.IOException: The parameter is incorrect.
    at com.codeminders.hidapi.HIDDevice.write(Native Method)
    at HIDTesting2.hidData.run(hidData.java:96)
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Java is "run anywhere" -- "byte" is always "byte" -- eight bits.

Comment: (But keep in mind that when you invoke a non JDK `native` method you're not calling Java -- it's system-dependent code and may, eg, depend on the flavor of path separator used on that particular system.)

Comment: You are calling a native method, so are you sure the implementations are the same on different OSes? The root of exception must be in native code.

Comment: Native method is only contract. Implementation is fully OS dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have read the instructions better for the hidapi API. "The first byte of data[] must contain the Report ID. For devices which only support a single report, this must be set to 0x0." Somewhat in my defense it worked just fine without that in my OSX 10.7.5 environment. My Arduino device got the message fine and I was able to process the byte[] array from the first element byte[0].  However when I ran the .jar on my XP computer the HID interface was looking for that 0x0 first byte. All I needed to do was change the code to pass that as the first byte of the buffer and both the Windows and Mac saw the write request fine.